# ldr lxf to urdf

Tags: urdf, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

is there a current nxt version for ros? We mostly need it to model the robots with LDD, then translating the files from ldr and lxf to urdf. But i didn't find any current build for nxt.
Or is it possible, to install the diamondback-build from ros_nxt and use these files with the hydro-build?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109631/ldr-lxf-to-urdf/) by [Nathan Schwarz](https://answers.ros.org/users/9411/nathan-schwarz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no idea as to its status, but there is [ToPitz/nxt_ros_catkin](https://github.com/ToPitz/nxt_ros_catkin) on GitHub.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0